# How can we sign my APK file using apksigner command in a Windows os which DOES NOT have AndroidSDK setup

Tags: android, apksigner

I could sign the APK file in windows by running the below command in the terminal which has Android SDK setup:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\apksigner
>   sign --ks testkeystore --ks-pass stdin --key-pass stdin --out
>   signed_app.apk app-debug.apk

I want to sign the APK file in a windows system which does not have Android setup, I have copied the ‘apksigner.bat’ and ‘apksigner.jar’ files in a folder and execute the below command but it is not working.

> C:\Users\username\Desktop\signing\apksigner sign --ks key --ks-pass
>   stdin --key-pass stdin --out signed_app.apk app-debug.apk

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "it is not working" - what happens?

Comment: APK signing is not happening, and not displaying any error message in the terminal. I further debug the apksigner.bat file, I have figured out that it is looking for 'find_java.bat" in the folder where I have copied apksigner.bat file.

"if exist    "%~dp0..\tools\lib\find_java.bat" call    "%~dp0..\tools\lib\find_java.bat"